# How to revoke the authorization to view my Google account for an app (e.g. Feedly)?

Tags: google-account, authorization

I recently installed Feedly on my phone. It asked me the authorization to access my Google account. Now I want to revoke this authorization, but I don't know how to do this.

I searched on my Google account (via web) under the *Security* part, but Feedly is not listed there.

I have an Android 4.3 stock ROM and, if important, my Google account is not a Google+ account.

Answer (score 3):

You need to go to the '[Connected sites and applications](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens)' section on the [security page](https://security.google.com/settings/security) and click 'Review Permissions'. From here you should see Feedly listed like this:

[image: Feedly]

Click the "Revoke Access" button and Feedly will no longer be able to access your account.

Comment: This was the part that I was talking about in my question. I don't have feedly listed there, I just give it my permission via the android app. I think you have this part because you logged via web to feedly too, I didn't do it.